# Automatically traverse a dynamically created jPanels for component values

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that creates a dynamic amount of jpanels and components based on selection at the start of the program that is user-defined.  having said that each jpanel and component is created with a loop making them all the same, and they are then put into a list (the JPanel's are put into a list).

Having said that I have been able to get the jpanel out and then grab the componenets and display them using System.out.  but they are in a component object.  How can I get the values of the components?  Or am I doing this wrong?

Basically I am trying to have the tabs/jpanels based on user-definition automatically generate, which works.  Then the user fills out some information and hits "Generate" which is where I then need to iterate through the tabs/jpanels/componenents and put them into the correct object.

Below is a working example of my program in a simplified for, with less tyteps of tabs (I only let the AP tab be created) and less options for the object classes:

There are two object classes APObject is extending Generic Object.  MVCE is the start of the main program where it asks you a few user-defined questions which generate the Tabs/Panels.  It then goes from InfoGathering.java to DataGathering where it creates the tabs and panels.  The GenerateActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) method is where I am trying to grab the information from the panel components and put them into the APObject or whichever object they need to go into.

```
MVCE:

    public class MVCE extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        int numGenerate[];
        private javax.swing.JComboBox cb;
        /**
         * Creates new form MVCE
         */
        public MVCE() {
            this.numGenerate = new int[3];
            initComponents();
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }));
            jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }));
            jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jLabel1.setText("How many switches?");

            jLabel2.setText("APS");

            jButton1.setText("Create Button");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addContainerGap(264, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            jLabel1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("How many switches");

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
           this.setVisible(false);
           InfoGathering Info = new InfoGathering(numGenerate);
        }                                        

        private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            cb = (javax.swing.JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String APNumber = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            //System.out.println(APNumber + "AP Number");
            numGenerate[1] = Integer.valueOf(APNumber);
        }                                          

        private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            cb = (javax.swing.JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String APNumber = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            //System.out.println(APNumber + "AP Number");
            numGenerate[0] = Integer.valueOf(APNumber);
        }                                          

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MVCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MVCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MVCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MVCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new MVCE().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }

INFOGATHERING:
public class InfoGathering {
   //public int infoVariables[];
   public InfoGathering(int[] infoVars) {
    startInfo(infoVars);
    } 

   private void startInfo(int[] infoVars) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DataGathering(infoVars).setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

   //End of clss below
}

DATAGATHERING:
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author kmalik
 */
public class DataGathering extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private int infoVariables[];
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel OuterPane;
    //SwitchObject SWOb[] = new SwitchObject[30];
    //APObject APOb[] = new APObject[30];
    //ControllerObject CoOb[] = new ControllerObject[1];
    //int devicesArrayCountSW = 0;
    //int devicesArrayCountAP = 0;
    //int devicesArrayCountCO = 0;



    /**
     * Creates new form DataGathering
     * @param intVars
     */
    public DataGathering(int[] intVars) {
        infoVariables = Arrays.copyOf(intVars, intVars.length);
        initComponents();
        initDynamic();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private void initDynamic() {
        OuterPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(OuterPane);
        OuterPane.add(jTabbedPane1);
        JButton GenerateCode = new JButton("Generate Code");
        OuterPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(OuterPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        OuterPane.add(GenerateCode);

        GenerateCode.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            private APObject Aobj;
            private JPanel jobj;
            private Component Components[];
            private Component components;
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                GenerateActionPerformed(evt);
            }

            private void GenerateActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
               //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                for(int i = 0; apList.size() > i; i++) {
                    //jobj = (JPanel) jList.get(i);
                    //System.out.println(jobj
                    Aobj = apList.get(i);
                    jobj = jList.get(i);
                    Components = jobj.getComponents();
                    System.out.println(Components + " Componenets of first panel");
                    for (int a=0; a < Components.length; a++) {
                        components = jobj.getComponent(a);
                        System.out.println(components);
                        if (Components[a] instanceof JComboBox) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        int SwitchCount = 1 , APCount = 1,CoCount = 1;
        //String jp;
        //need public# of switches, APs and controllers

        for(int devicesCount =0;devicesCount < infoVariables.length;devicesCount++) {
            if (devicesCount == 2 && infoVariables[devicesCount] == 1) {
                createTab(CoCount, devicesCount);
            }
            for(int b=0; b < infoVariables[devicesCount]; b++) {
             if (devicesCount == 0) {
                //SWITCHES DYNAMICALLY CREATE
                createTab(SwitchCount,devicesCount);
                SwitchCount++;
             } else if (devicesCount==1) {
                //AP DYNAMICALLY CREATE
                 createTab(APCount,devicesCount);
                 APCount++;
             } //end of full if loop         
            } //end of for loop
        } // end of outer for loop
    }                     
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;




   //ArrayList<SwitchObject> swList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<APObject> apList = new ArrayList<>();
    //ArrayList<ControllerObject> coList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<JPanel> jList = new ArrayList<>();
    private void createTab(int z,int y) {
        if (y==0) {
           //CREATE SWITCH TAB/PANEL


        } else if (y==1) {
           JPanel jp = new JPanel();
           jTabbedPane1.addTab("AP_"+z,jp);
           jp.setName("AP"+z);
           APObject APOb = new APObject(jp.getName(), z);
           apList.add(APOb);
           jList.add(jp);

           setLayout(new FlowLayout());

           //Add Type of Device Checkbox
           String[] apListName = {"APExample1","APExample2"};
           JComboBox apListChkBox = new JComboBox(apListName);
           jp.add(apListChkBox);

           //Add NasID of Device with Label
           JLabel apnasIDLabel = new JLabel("AP ID");
           String apnasID;
           JTextField apnasIDComboBox = new JTextField();
           apnasIDComboBox.setColumns(9);
           jp.add(apnasIDLabel);
           jp.add(apnasIDComboBox);

           //SNMP Location
           JLabel apLocLabel = new JLabel("Location");
           String apLoc;
           JTextField apLocComboBox = new JTextField();
           apLocComboBox.setColumns(9);
           jp.add(apLocLabel);
           jp.add(apLocComboBox);

           jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
           this.pack();

        } else if (y == 2) {
           //CREATE CONTROLLER TAB/PANEL
        }
    }
}

APOBJECT:
public class APObject extends GenericObject {
    private int channelScheme;


    APObject(String x, int y) {
        super(x,y);
    }

    //ip scheme box/subnet box get/set

    //location get/set

    //channel scheme get/set

    private void setChannelScheme(int x) {
        channelScheme = x;
    }

    private int getChannelScheme() {
        return channelScheme;
    }

}

GENERICOBJECT:
public class GenericObject {
    private int telephone;
    private String ipScheme;
    private String Location;
    public String DName;


    public int getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    protected void setTelephone(int x) {
        telephone = x;
    }

    protected String getipScheme() {
        return ipScheme;
    }

    protected void setipScheme(String x) {
        ipScheme = x;
    }

    protected String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    protected void setLocation(String x) {
        Location = x;
    }

    public GenericObject (String SName, int Tab) {
        DName = SName;
        int TabNum = Tab;
    }


}
```

Comment: What similar objects are the added panels describing?  What is an `APObject`?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I will work on a MCVE.  But for now, basically each panel has a combobox, textfield, combobox and a textfield.  APObject is a class I made which extends GenericObject.  It is the object that holds all the information that is being input in by the user.

Say you select 5 AP objects and 5 Switch Objects for example.  It creates 10 tabs each with its own panel.  Then you fill in each panel and hit generate and it needs to put the info from the panels into the correct object.  

So i need a way to get each components value from each panel sequentially and put it into the corresponding object.

Comment: *"I will work on a MCVE. But for now,.."*  ..I will wait for the MCVE.

Comment: I modified and added a working copy of my code.  I labeled each .java file at the top of the code and put it into code quotes.